# Rails - Pundit undefined method 'user'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, pundit

I am trying to implement a policy that restricts the creation of a post to either admin or a business.  In turn only the record owner(business) who created the post or admin can edit. But i get an error saying 'undefined method user' can anyone help out here?

Schema.rb

```
create_table "users", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "email",                  default: "",    null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "",    null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,     null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "confirmation_token"
    t.datetime "confirmed_at"
    t.datetime "confirmation_sent_at"
    t.string   "unconfirmed_email"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "role"

create_table "posts", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "content"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "user_id"
  end
```

User.rb

```
def admin?
    role == 'admin'
  end

  def biz?
    role == 'biz'
  end
```

Post_controller

```
def edit
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
     authorize @post
  end
```

Post.show.html.erb

```
<% if policy(@post).edit? %>
    <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(@post) %> |
  <% end %>
```

Application.policy

```
def create?
    user.present? && ( user.admin? || user.biz?)
  end

  def new?
    create?
  end

  def update?
    user.present? && (record.user == user || user.admin?)
  end

  def edit?
    update?
  end
```

Comment: Two things: (1) will you post the output of your error because there isn't enough information listed to debug it, and (2) please show the entire application policy so i can see how the file is set up.

Answer (score 0):

If you got an **"undefined method user"** error, that means that the **user is nil**, and you are calling `policy(@post).edit?` in your *show* view of post, that means that it searches through the edit method defined in your post_policy.rb file *(or directly to your application_policy.rb if you don't have a post_policy.rb file)* `def edit?`, which in turn calls the update method `def update?` and finally the update method is being called as:

```
def update?
  user.present? && (record.user == user || user.admin?)
end
```

Which means that user is nil, and you are calling `record.user`, that's the problem here, because `record` is not calling anything, you need to **double check your post model and make sure a post belongs to a user**.

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```